# How to add "publish content" to a node view tab

Tags: nodes, routes

I'm developping a website where I'm asked to add a tab "Publish content" next to the Edit tab. I was told to use the hook_menu, but so far i didn't succeed in showing the tab.

Here is what I have done so far :

```
function mij_bo_add_menu(){
    global $items;
    $items['node/%node/edit'] = array(
        'title' => t('Publish'),
        'page callback' => 'node_page_view',
        'page arguments' => $items['#primary'][1]['#link']['page_arguments'],
        'access callback' => 'node_access',
        'access arguments' => array(1),
        'weight' => 5,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );
 }
```

Any suggestions?

PS : I am still a novice in Drupal programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a module called [Publish Content](https://www.drupal.org/project/publishcontent) that does what you exactly describe. You can browse the [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/publishcontent/tree/) if you want to see how it's implemented there.

Comment: Unfortunately this module doesn't allow checkbox or ajax link

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to create a GLOBAL flag to be used by authorized editors. For any node for which the flag is turned on, let the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module update the status to published. Done ... No coding needed/involved.

The actual implementation of such flag can either be:

- a link somewhere when viewing the node (click such link to toggle the flag on/off).
- a checkbox to be turned on/off while editing the node.

If you're not familiar with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework). And/or the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. Especially the video tutorial about [Triggering Rules with Flag](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/triggering-rules-with-flag) is pretty close to what you want to do here: instead of changing the some of the node access permissions (as in the video), you just want to change the node status to published.

Note:
The video [How to add a Flag link to a Drupal View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epzLPj_VboA) shows how to add a flag to a view.